# jquery mobile - Style and script of dynamic content does not work on revisiting the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

New to jquery mobile. trying to build my first jquery mobile app.
App requirement is some pages with left and right panel. There is a lot of dynamic data like Page title, left panel list(which contains image and heading through JSON object), right panel which has all the page links will also come dynamically. 
Everything works fine at first but after visiting page 2 when we revisit  page 1,  panels messed up. page title does not update. 
It seems that revisiting the page does not catch the styles and functions written on js and css files.
Here is the demo. 
HTML
https://jsfiddle.net/brunocoder/x5j0jqgt/3/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-1"  data-title="Page 1" class="header-default footer-default ">
    <div data-role="panel" id="page-1-panel-left" data-dismissible="false" class="panel-left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-position="left">
    </div><!--end panel-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="page-1-panel-right" class="ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right panel-right" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="panel-right-listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#page-1" data-rel="close" class="panel-header">Close</a></li>
            <div class="app-page-list"></div><!--dynamic list of pages-->
        </ul>
    </div><!--end panel right-->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false">
        <a href="#page-1-panel-left" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>

        <a href="#page-1-panel-right" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-gear" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"></a>
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div data-role="main" class="">
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 1<br/>Div 1
        <br/> Click on right panel</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 1<br/>Div 2</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 1<br/>Div 3</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 1<br/>Div 4</div><!--end chart box-->

    </div><!--main ends here-->

</div><!--end page-1 page-->

<div data-role="page" id="page-2"  data-title="Page 2" class="header-default footer-default">
    <div data-role="panel" id="page-2-panel-left" class="panel-left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-position="left">
    </div>
    <!--end panel-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="page-2-panel-right" class="ui-panel-content-wrap-position-right panel-right" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
        <ul data-role="listview" class="panel-right-listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#page-1" data-rel="close" class="panel-header">Close</a></li>
            <div class="app-page-list"></div><!--dynamic list of pages-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--end panel right-->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false">
        <a href="#page-2-panel-left" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>

        <a href="#page-2-panel-right" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-gear" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"></a>
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div data-role="main">
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 2<br/>Div 1<br/>click right panel to go on Page 1.</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 2<br/>Div 2</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 2<br/>Div 3</div><!--end chart box-->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all page-box">This is page 2<br/>Div 4</div><!--end chart box-->

    </div><!--main ends here-->
</div>
<!--page ends here-->
```

JS
    // below code for dynamic header

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role='page']", function(){
    if($($(this)).hasClass("header-default")){
        $('<div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false"><h1>'+ '' +'</h1></div>')
        .prependTo( $(this) )
        .toolbar({position: "fixed"});
        $("[data-role='header'] h1").text($(this).jqmData("title"));
    } //header default

    if ($($(this)).hasClass("footer-default")){
        $('<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="false"></div>')
        .appendTo($(this))
        .toolbar({position: "fixed"});
    }
});// show page
// dyynamic footer

// code for dynamic page list
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role='page']", function(){
    //This code creates dynamic list of dashboards
    var PageList = '<li><a href="#page-1" class="ui-btn ">page 1</a></li>';
    PageList += '<li><a href="#page-2" class="ui-btn ">page 2</a></li>';
    $(".app-page-list").html(PageList);

});


// dynamic panel list page-1
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role='page']", function(){
    var ChartData = {
        results: [
            {
                chart_id: "box-1",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-1.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 1"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-2",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-2.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 2"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-3",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-3.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 3"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-4",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-1.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 4"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-5",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-2.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 5"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-6",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-3.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 6"
            }
        ]
    };
    var panel_list = '<ul data-role="listview" id="" data-inset="true" class="app-panel" >';
    panel_list +='<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="panel-header ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete"> Close</a></li>';

    var res = ChartData.results;
    for (var key in res)
    {
        panel_list += '<li data-icon="false">';
        panel_list += '<a data-transition="slide" href=#'+ res[key].chart_id +'>';
        panel_list += '<img class="orange-border" src="'+res[key].chart_image+'">';
        panel_list += '<p>'+ res[key].chart_title +'</p>';
        panel_list += '</a></li>';
        // console.info(res[key].chart_title);
    }
    panel_list += '</ul>';
    $("#page-1-panel-left").html(panel_list);
});

// dynamic panel list page-2
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "[data-role='page']", function(){
    var page_2_ChartData = {
        results: [
            {
                chart_id: "box-7",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-3.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 1"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-8",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-1.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 2"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-9",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-2.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 3"
            },
            {
                chart_id: "box-10",
                chart_image: "images/panel-chart-3.jpg",
                chart_title: "chart 4"
            }
        ]
    };
    var page_2_panel_list = '<ul data-role="listview" id="" data-inset="true" class="app-panel" >';
    page_2_panel_list +='<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="panel-header ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete"> Close</a></li>';

    var page_2_res = page_2_ChartData.results;
    for (var key in page_2_res)
    {
        page_2_panel_list += '<li data-icon="false">';
        page_2_panel_list += '<a data-transition="slide" href=#'+ page_2_res[key].chart_id +'>';
        page_2_panel_list += '<img class="orange-border" src="'+page_2_res[key].chart_image+'">';
        page_2_panel_list += '<p>'+ page_2_res[key].chart_title +'</p>';
        page_2_panel_list += '</a></li>';
        // console.info(res[key].chart_title);
    }
    page_2_panel_list += '</ul>';
    $("#page-2-panel-left").html(page_2_panel_list);
});
```

CSS

```
 .page-box{
        width:90%;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .panel-header{
        min-height: 1.3em !important;
        background-color: #4eb1ba !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 1em !important;
    }
    .ui-panel-inner>.ui-listview-inset{
        margin: -1em;
    }
    .orange-border{
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 2px solid #FBD073 !important;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .panel-right.ui-panel{
        width: 12em;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .panel-left.ui-panel{
        width: 8em;
    }    
    .ui-panel-inner{
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .app-panel>li>a>img{
        position: relative !important;
        clear: both;
        background-color: #999999;
        height: 90px;
        width: 90px;
    }
    .app-panel>.ui-li-has-thumb>.ui-btn, .ui-.app-panel>.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb{
        padding: 1.7em !important;
        background-color: #ffffff !important;

    }
    .panel-right-listview{
        margin: -1em 0em 0em 0em !important;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pagecreate you are calling:

```
$("[data-role='header'] h1").text($(this).jqmData("title"));
```

This writes the text to all header h1's in the DOM, so when you visit page 2 it is also overwriting the one on page 1.  Change the line to:

```
$(this).find("[data-role='header'] h1").text($(this).jqmData("title"));
```

This ensures you are only updating the header within the page being created.

For the panel, as you have separate handlers for each page, change the handlers to

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#page-1", function(){ ...
```

and

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#page-2", function(){ ...
```

This ensures they only run once for the page about to be created.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x5j0jqgt/4/)**